# Max count of coordinates within a radius

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry, geolocation

Given a list of enemy coordinates x and y, and a damage radius r of your missile, find the best coordinate  (cx, cy) to detonate the bomb to kills the most number of enemy.

My first intuition was to target the centroid of the enemies (average of all coordinates), but it seems wrong, because if the enemies clusters in 3 camps far from each other, the centroid would be hitting nobody.

Is there a polynomial time Algorithm to solve this problem? It seems like a combinatorial problem. How is this problem commonly called?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-algorithm-for-enclosing-the-maximum-number-of-points-in-a-2-D-plane-with-a-fixed-radius-circle

Comment: It appears you have a known (non-continuous) function f(x,y) that equals the number of enemy killed it you drop a bomb at location (x,y), and you are trying to select (x,y) over an area to maximize that function. Depending on the data you may be able to treat the function as a continuous one having first derivatives relative to x and y. Then, starting from any (x,y), estimate those partial derivatives numerically and use Newton's method to take small (delta-x, delta-y) steps towards a local maximum of the function...

Comment: ...A (strict) local maximum is a point (x,y) at which the value of the function decreases for all small changes to x and/or y. Even if you are successful in identifying a local maximum, however, there is no assurance that it would be the global maximum you are looking for. You could perhaps do that for several starting points but you'll never be able to prove that you've found the optimal solution. As there are an infinite number of target locations I don't believe a polynomial-time solution exists. Nor do I see how it can be viewed as a combinatorial problem.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this problem commonly called?

Your problem falls in the field of Cluster Analysis ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis )

There are numerous algorithms available.  But before getting into those, we should, if only for performance comparison, code a simple grid search to find an aim point that covers the greatest number of targets.

```
void gridSearch(double radius)
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("gridSearch");
    theMax2 = radius * radius;
    bestCount = 0;
    for (double y = 1; y < theDim; y++)
        for (double x = 1; x < theDim; x++)
        {
            cxy aim((int)x, (int)y);
            int count = countNeighbors( aim );
            if (count > bestCount)
            {
                bestCount = count;
                bestAim = aim;
            }
        }
}
```

My favorite clustering algorithm is k-means ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering ).  It seems to give good results in all sorts of different situations.  My code for implementing this is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/KMeans.  Here is the code that applies it to your particular problem:

```
void findClustersKMeans(double radius)
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("findClustersKMeans");

    // Construct the KMeans class
    KMeans KM;

    theMax2 = radius * radius;

    // loop over data
    for (cxy &l : vTarget)
    {
        // construct data point
        cDataPoint dp(2);
        dp.d[0] = l.x;
        dp.d[1] = l.y;

        // add data point to KMeans
        KM.Add(dp);
    }

    // Initialize KMeans with required number of clusters
    KM.Init(4, false);

    // run KMeans algorithm to find clusters
    KM.Iter(20);

    bestCount = 0;
    for (auto &c : KM.clusters())
    {
        cxy aim;
        aim.x = c.center().d[0];
        aim.y = c.center().d[1];
        int count = countNeighbors( aim );
        if( count > bestCount )
        {
            bestCount = count;
            bestAim = aim;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the graphical display of the results of a test run.

[image]

Here is the performance table for test runs with different numbers of targets

| targets | grid hits | k-means hits | grid msecs | k-means msecs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 28 | 22 | 33 | 5 |
| 1,000 | 229 | 223 | 300 | 50 |
| 5,000 | 1037 | 1016 | 1700 | 380 |

The complete application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/ClusterFinder

---

To make this work most relevant to you, I would need your target count and performance requirements. ( Somehow you forgot to include these!!! )

Some ideas:

- The grid search performance depends greatly on the grid resolution.  Reducing the search resolution give a dramatic improvement in performance for a small loss in accuracy.
- If this needs to be run many times with the same data, then the up-front cost of storing the targets in a quadtree will give a significant performance boost compared to searching through every target.  For details on how this works and code to implement it:  https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree
- Implement and compare the performance of other clustering algorithms.  Here is a list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cluster_analysis_algorithms.  I would not expect any huge improvement from k-means, so this will only be worthwhile if you care about shaving off a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any possible blast circle that contains at least 2 enemies, then there is an optimal blast circle with at least 2 enemies on its edge.

For each pair of enemies that are no further apart than the blast circle diameter, there are two circles with the right diameter that they both touch.

Test them all.